# "Раскопай своих подвалов..." — правильно или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Все помнят стихотворение Привалова из "Понедельник начинается в субботу":
*Раскопай своих подвалов

И шкафов перетряси.

Всяких книжек и журналов

По возможности неси.*

А вообще, можно ли так говорить "раскопай *своих подвалов*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, конечно, потому что у неодушевленных существительных винительный падеж совпадает не с родительным, а с именительным

Answer (score 1):

> А вообще, можно ли так говорить "раскопай своих подвалов"?

Можно. Говорите. Только не забывайте ссылок давать на Привалова.

P. S. Это не винительный. Это одесский родительный. "Вы хочете шуток? **Их** у меня есть"